# Kinesis freestyle 2: Keyboard shortcuts and side buttons (Undo, cut, copy, paste buttons) do not work on macbook

Tags: mac, keyboard-shortcuts

The Kinesis Freestyle 2 is great, but I cannot use the shortcuts to copy, paste, cut, and find things. when I connected the keyboard to my Mac, I did not do anything to program the keyboard. Am I missing anything? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Presumably, you don't have the Mac-specific version. One for Windows would be sending Ctrl/C etc, the Mac wants to see Cmd/C. Try [Key Codes](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/key-codes/id414568915?mt=12) (freeware) to see what it's sending.